# Store user input when updating repeater inside updatepanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I have a repeater inside UpdatePanel. Inside repeater item I have several text boxes. I also have "Add New" button to dynamically add new items to the repeater. The problem is that every time I press "Add New" all user input is erased. How do I update repeater with preserving user input?

Comment: How are you storing what is added already to the repeater? What is the datasource of it?

Comment: Are you doing any `PostBack, or IsPostBack` checking in your code..? update panel should do `partial PostBack` can you post some relevant code..?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a `Postback` occurs, `Repeater` control loses its state. You might want to perform following quick steps on a Postback.

1. Convert repeater data to some form of data array (DA) in code-behind.
2. Add empty element to DA.
3. Bind DA back to Repeater control.

Comment: With enabled `ViewState`(default) the repeater retains it's state across postbacks. So it all depends on the datasource and when he databinds the repeater. It should be done only if `!IsPostBack` or when new items were added.

Comment: My problem is that when I press "Add New" I rebind the entire DataSource, which causes reset of all values to their original state. So the question is how to populate changes from HTML back to DataSource? Should I write a method to manually extract value from each field in the repeater and update my objects? Or there is a simpler built-in way to sync in-memory objects with repeater HTML.